# Assign parent object type to child object in Python

Tags: python, polymorphism

I am an experienced Java developer that recently picked up Python. Whilest trying some stuff out, I couldn't find any solution online for folowing problem:

```py
class A()
    def __init__(self, **data: Any) -> None:
        self.a1 = data['a1']
        self.a2 = data['a2']

    a1: str
    a2: str


class B(A)
    def __init__(self, **data: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(**data)
        self.b1 = data['b1']

    b1: str

def map_to_a(some_data) -> A:
    return A(a1=some_data['a1'], a2=some_data['a2'])


def map_to_b(some_data) -> B:
    b: B = map_to_a(some_data)
    b.b1 = some_data['b1'] # ==> ERROR happens here since b is of type A because map_to_a returns A so b
    return b
```

The result is:

```
ValueError: "A" object has no field "b1"
```

How can I solve this easily? Is there a way to perhaps maybe cast my A to a B object? I can't find the solution online.

The reason I want it like this, is that I don't have to map all my fields of object type A twice (once in map_to_a and once in map_to_b).

Comment: The underlying object is still an `A` - so how would you use the same object again with `b1`? You need to create another object.

Comment: You can avoid duplication by putting the mapping logic in `A` in a different method & then use that in `B`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a trivial cast method here. You can monkey around with `__class__` stuff, but it's not advised. Broadly speaking you'll need to just create some initializer or method based on A to create a new B, not some cast of an existing object.